# запрос на минимальное и максимальное значение

Tags: mysql

Всем привет. Есть 3 таблицы: field, posts, values.

**Таблица field:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Таблица values:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Таблица posts:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице **values** находятся только значения, которые привязаны к названиям полей в таблице **field** и к машинам в таблице **posts** по **id**. Как можно найти максимальное и минимальное значение, например из всех полей "год выпуска" в таблице **values**, которая связана с таблицей **field**?? Значений в таблице **values** привязанных к названиям полей в таблице **field** всего 5 - **2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005**. Помогите пожалуйста написать запрос для нахождения min и max значений.

Comment: Замените скриншоты на fiddle, или хотя бы CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO в виде текста. И дайте требуемый ответ для именно таких данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял суть вопроса, то вот:

`SELECT MAX(values.value), MIN(values.value) FROM values LEFT JOIN field ON field.id = values.field_id`